# Finding similar images in specfic parent folder to specific only image

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, photos, file-search

I have a photo, I want to search an entire directory for similar photos to this photo.

Having the same image quality/image name is not guaranteed. they are basically the same image but being uploaded to different services.

Is there any program to do that?

Comment: Having the same image quality/image name is not guarnateed. they are basically the same image but being uploaded to different services, dont know how applications handled it there.

Comment: Thanks.  Question updated.

Comment: IMHO will be better to ask you question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you looking for a duplicate finder?